# Allow interactivity on UIViewController below presented UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

Im presenting a `UIViewController` with a `UIModalPresentationCustom` presentation style and the presented `UIViewController` has it's main view's `backgroundColor` set to `clearColor`.  I need to allow interactions to the `UIViewController` that sits below.  Is this possible?

The reason Im doing this is that I have a map that needs to persistently sit below a presented `UINavigationController` and I need to allow interactions with it.  The presented views may have content that scrolls above it, and at that time I'd like interactivity to stop (which it should by default).

Comment: It is not possible, as this would make for too much incoherency. :) Consider some other interface. (I remember when I first experimented with the interface you describe, I was worried that maybe interaction with the "behind" view controller's view _would_ be possible, and I was glad when this turned out not to be the case.)

Comment: yeah, Im starting to agree.  too many things to look out for.  We've designed another way around this!  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this by messing with hitTest, though I wouldn't rely on that.

It seems like a popover with 'passthroughViews' might serve your purposes better.  If you can't deal with the arrow, you can always set a custom UIPopoverBackgroundView.

Comment: thanks, I thought about a popover as well, but we need really need this to be a UINavigationController look and feel.

Comment: You can have a UINavigationController in a popover, but I understand your pain.  Perhaps just use view controller containment rather than presentation.